# Get the first element of list if it exists in dart

Tags: arrays, list, dart

I was wondering if there is a way to access the first element of a list in dart if an element exists at all, and otherwise return null.

First, I thought this would do the job:

```
final firstElement = myList?.first;
```

This works if myList is null or myList.length > 0, but would give me an error if myList is an empty List.

I guess I could do something like this:

```
final firstElement = (myList?.length ?? 0) > 0 ? myList.first : null;
```

But I was wondering if there is a simpler way of doing what I'm trying to do out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note `List<T>.firstOrNull` is available in Dart >= 3.0.0, `package:collection` no longer required.

Answer (score 86):

UPDATE: since Dart 3.0, `package:collection` is no longer required to use method `firstOrNull`. Thanks to @Mrb83 for pointing this out.

<s>Now you can import `package:collection` and use the extension method firstOrNull</s>

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {

  final myList = [];

  final firstElement = myList.firstOrNull;

  print(firstElement); // null
}
```

Comment: It is the real answer! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 17):

For Dart 2.12 (with null-safety) adding an extension function might be a good idea:

```dart
extension MyIterable<T> on Iterable<T> {
  T? get firstOrNull => isEmpty ? null : first;

  T? firstWhereOrNull(bool Function(T element) test) {
    final list = where(test);
    return list.isEmpty ? null : list.first;
  }
}
```

Comment: In `firstWhereOrNull` why not just reusing `firstOrNull`? `T? firstWhereOrNull(bool Function(T element) test) => where(test).firstOrNull;`

Answer (score 1):

As you may have already guessed, you need to implement such functionality yourself and since [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/177) and/or [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/177) are still open, there is no minimalistic version of doing it (i.e. through extension functions).

So we should do the longer version:

```
E firstOrNull<E>(List<E> list) {
  return list == null || list.isEmpty ? null : list.first;
}
```

**Edit:** As mentioned by @Mattia there will be support for static extension functions in version 2.6 (currently in beta).

Comment: As of Dart 2.6 (currently in beta), `Static Extensions Methods` ( https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/41 ) could be used: `extension MyList<T> on List<T> {
  T get firstOrNull => this.isEmpty ? null : this.first;
}`