# Access first element of a nullable List<String> in Dart

Tags: dart, nullable

I'm loading a custom object 'selectedBox' from my server. Some Boxes don't have item images, then the property item_images has size = 0:

[image]

Now I need to access the first image (and display it to the user). If the box has no image, I want to show a default image:

```
String itemUrl = widget.selectedBox.item_images?[0] ??
    'https://enso-box.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Allura+-+Park.png';
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446296/get-the-first-element-of-list-if-it-exists-in-dart), I think this should work, but instead it throws an error when the selectedBox has no item images:

RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Following works, but this can't be the best solution:

```
   List<String> itemImages = widget.selectedBox.item_images ??
    []; // first make sure that .item_images is not null
if (itemImages.length == 0) {
  itemImages = [
    'https://enso-box.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Allura+-+Park.png'
  ];
}
log(itemImages[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the first element of an empty list, and you get an error if you try. So you must not try.
Using `?[0]` doesn't work because the list is not `null`, it's just empty. It's precisely the same as `[0]` on the empty list.

The way to avoid that would be checking before accessing:

```dart
  log(itemImages.isNotEmpty ? itemImages.first : 'your-default-value')
```

If that's too long for you, you can use the [`firstOrNull`](https://pub.dev/documentation/dartlin/latest/collections/FirstOrNull/firstOrNull.html) from `package:collection`.

```dart
import "package:collection/collection.dart";
// ...
  log(itemImages.firstOrNull ?? 'your-default-value');
```

If your value is *also* nullable, I'd probably go with:

```dart
  log(itemImages?.firstOrNull ?? 'your-default-value');
```

(The `?.firstOrNull` means the result becomes `null` if the list is `null` *or* empty.)

Comment: But when I do this, I receive `The property 'isNotEmpty' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.` because itemImages is of type `List<String>?`

Comment: @G-Unit you cannot check `.isNotEmpty` on a nullable property. One way of fixing this would be to add a null check:
`log(itemImages != null && itemImages!.isNotEmpty ? itemImages.first : 'your-default-value')` (note the '!' operator on the second condition)