# In Dart, how do I get the first item of a List or null, if empty?

Tags: flutter, dart

Every time I want the first item or null, I do this:

```
final paragraphNodes = findNodes(node, (p) => p.type == 'p');
final paragraphNode = paragraphNodes.isNotEmpty ? paragraphNodes.first : null;
```

I could use `Iterable.first` but it doesn't return null, it throws an exception.

```
// `first` throws an exception if the list is empty
final paragraphNodes = findNodes(node, (p) => p.type == 'p').first;
```

How do I, in one line, return the first item of a list, or null?

Comment: make the list nullable using the ? operator. You have to define type when creating list eg List<String>? myList

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following solution by using `import package:collection` and use the extension method firstOrNull:

[Get the first element of list if it exists in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446296/get-the-first-element-of-list-if-it-exists-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

firstOrNull is now implemented in dart >=3.0.0.

in pubspec.yaml set and run "dart pub get"

```
environment:
  sdk: ^3.0.0
```

you code:

```
final paragraphNodes = findNodes(node, (p) => p.type == 'p');
final paragraphNode = paragraphNodes.firstOrNull;
```